# Hiding menu according to permission in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to check if user has permission, if he does not have permission the menu item will not appear.

I'm trying to check through `@UserManager.GetUserName(User)`, but I can not get all the data contained in the Identity table to see if user has permission, in the example below he does not recognize the word "Cidades".

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="presentation">
     @if (UserManager.GetUserName(User.Cidades) == true)
     {
        <li><a asp-page="/Cidade/Index">Cidades</a></li>
     }
```

In a page with controller I do it this way and it works well:

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            bool cidade = user.Cidades;
            if ( cidade == true)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Error");
            }
```

How would be the right way to do it in the _Layout.cshtml view?

Answer (score 3):

Use [View-bsed authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Basically it says:

1. inject authorization service

   @inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService
2. Use the service as follow

   @if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "PolicyName")).Succeeded)
   {

   This paragraph is displayed because you fulfilled PolicyName.

   }

An important notice:

> Don't rely on toggling visibility of your app's UI elements as the sole authorization check.

Comment: In case the " PolicyName" is an Identity table field? By doing so I get an error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No policy found: Cidades.